# Meltdown Patching can be turned on as needed

Tags: sql-server-2012, patching

Experts,

Need to know if anyone has witnessed or found such settings while patching SQL servers for Meltdown patches.

Our sys admins informed that OS patches for Meltdown can be turned ON/OFF bases on registry setting and can be enabled or disabled.

Just looking if someone know a similar way available for SQL server patches? Means you can turn it active when needed?

Comment: So you would turn them on right before someone tries to hack you, and then turn them back off afterwards, eh? I like it.

Comment: @BrentOzar- :), I am just saying , you know. Its like i heard and people here are buzzing if there can be a pause, means not turning it on instantly. They say its there on OS patch, even though i could not find a blog for that. So was thinking if any one has witnessed the same or implemented if possible :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no publicly known way to do this for the SQL Server Meltdown/Spectre patches.

Microsoft might have a trace flag to do it, but if so, they haven't shared it publicly as of yet.